# how to remove delimiters from string-ref output in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Say you have `"345"` and want the numerical representation of `"5"`.

If you use `(string-ref "345" 2)` you get `#\3`.

How can I get this character without the `#\` delimiters ? My end goal is to convert this to a number.

Comment: Use `string` to convert characters to strings, and convert string to number using `string->number`. For example: `(string->number (string (string-ref "345" 2)))` outputs `5`.

Answer (score 3):

#\3 is the scheme representation of the single character 3 (just like some other languages may represent it as '3').

`(char->integer #\3)` will give you the character code (51), while `(- (char->integer (string-ref "345" 2)) (char->integer #\0))` will give you the numeric value of your digit.